# I want draw image in two row in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, grid, xamarin.forms

[image]

I make app for android in VS2015.
I want to make a grid layout like upper image.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="BackImage" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>              

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="Text1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Text="Text2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

I draw image before divide row.
But image is only draw in row 0 like this.
I want to use row no.0&1 like 1 row.

Comment: please inline your images, instead of linking to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you're looking for is this:

```xml
<Image x:Name="BackImage" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

`RowSpan`, and `ColumnSpan`, instruct the `Grid` layout system that you want the object to span over multiple rows, or columns.

declaring the image before the `RowDefinitions` won't change anything.